# Is it possible to install Doctrine without PEAR or Composer? If so, how?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, pear, composer-php

My hosting provider doesn't allow using Composer or PEAR. [Doctrine manual](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-2-3-4.html) doesn't mention any other way of installing it.

**How do I install Doctrine without using PEAR or Composer?**

Comment: i) You can run Composer through a browser - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219436/run-composer-with-a-php-script-in-browser/17244866#17244866 ii) Get a new host.

Answer (score 2):

You can visit this page https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2 and then Download ZIP at the right side of the page. Additional Doctrine related stuff can be found here https://github.com/doctrine and here https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions

EDIT: you can also install your vendors with composer locally and upload your vendor folder with your app when you have a production ready version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PEAR to install the packages locally and then ftp/scp it up to your host: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php

This way you can use PEAR locally and don't need it on your server.