# PHP Composer can't find composer.json file for my project

Tags: composer-php

I have successfully installed Composer in the root directory (that was the default choice) on my Linux/Apache server using their installation guide. It's all been very simple so far, except for one php.ini tweak I've had to make (`detect_unicode = Off`) but now I'm stuck.

I'm trying to install Ratchet using Composer, with the use of this guide:

http://socketo.me/docs/install

It says I need to "*create a file called composer.json in your project folder*". So I created that file (with the contents they gave on their page) using the cPanel file manager, in my application's root directory. However, when I run Composer using:

```
php composer.phar install
```

PuTTy gives the following error message:

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in /root
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the http://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
```

But this doesn't seem to make sense, why would I place the JSON file in the server's root if the documentation says to place it in the project folder? What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you're executing *php composer.phar install* in /root path.

Comment: Oh, so I should cd to the proper directory first? Makes sense.

Answer (score 17):

I just found on other topic that you can use :

```
php composer.phar --working-dir=/home/user/folder/ update
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect. Much more simple than http://stackoverflow.com/a/25208897/1123127.