# Composer vendor/ folder FTP upload

Tags: php, ftp, composer-php, production

I have a local project with loaded with Composer libs. I uploaded this project to my FTP and received errors, connected with not found classes from some libs.

Can I simply copy `vendor/` folder to FTP or I missed something?

Error received:
`Fatal error: Class 'AAA\Core\Tools' not found in /home/aaa/public_html/api.php on line 11`

`api.php`:

```
<?php
    use AAA\Core\Tools;

    require_once("./vendor/autoload.php");
    require_once("./api/" . Tools::getFieldValue('controller') . ".php");
```

All works fine on `localhost`!

Comment: Did you run the `install` command after uploading?

Comment: @l'L'l No, I have run `composer install` on my local copy, composer created `vendor/` folder with all staff and I uploaded it to the FTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux has a case sensitive file system. That means that files `Alex.txt` and `alex.txt` are the same thing in Windows, but not in Linux. Actually on Linux both can happily live in the same directory:

```
$ tree .                                                    
.
├── alex.txt
└── Alex.txt

0 directories, 2 files
```

Taking this into consideration, I would try to double check that the paths you are using in your namespace are actually identical to what is found at the file system level. (*i.e: `AAA` directory with only uppercase letters ; `Core` directory capitalized and `Tools.php` file capitalized*)

---

If you want to keep your existing file system layout, you can use PSR-4 to  explicitly tell Composer how to map the namespace to the file system:

1. Change `autoload` section from your composer.json:

   ```
   {
       "autoload": {
           "psr-4": {"AAA\\DB\\": "db/"}
       }
   }
   ```

   *where `db/` is the actual path from the file system*
2. Update the autoloader:

   ```
   $ composer dump-autoload
   ```

This will take care of directory names, but doesn't apply for files. Meaning that any file inside `db/` must be named exactly as used in namespace (*for a usage as `use AAA\DB\DBCore` the file **must** be `db/DBCore.php`*).

If your file is named `dbcore.php` and you want to reference it in your namespace as `DBCore`, you can use [classmap](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#classmap) feature from Composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "db/dbcore.php"
    ]
}
```

dbcore.php:

```
<?php

namespace AAA\DB;

class DBCore
{
}
```

And you can use it as usual:

```
<?php
require_once("./vendor/autoload.php");
$dbCore = new \AAA\DB\DBCore();
```

Comment: Can I somehow alias lower case folder names to uppercase in namespaces, for example I have `db/` folder but want to use it like `use AAA\DB\DBCore`?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would check the autoloader files composer has generated to make sure the paths are valid on your linux server.

Another simple but common issue is that on windows the folder and file names are not case sensitive however they are on Linux. Double check that the folders and files have the correct case as if not it won't find them to auto load.

Comment: Can I somehow alias lower case folder names to uppercase in namespaces, for example I have `db/` folder but want to use it like `use AAA\DB\DBCore`?

Comment: You should be able to do that in your composer.json as Alexandru has described in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to upload via FTP which I think is going to be tricky if not impossible to get right, I would suggest you explore getting composer working on your hosting environment.

Composer is entirely PHP based, so should run anywhere that PHP is running.

If you don't have command line access, you can use something like [PHPShell](http://phpshell.sourceforge.net/) which gives you a PHP based command line on which you can then run Composer.

[See this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26277355/543455) to get some tips on how to use PHPShell.

Another option is to build a little PHP wrapper that you actually run by visiting it in your browser, in the classic PHP way. [See this other SO answer for some tips on how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244866/543455).

Bottom line, you should really look at getting Composer running on your server rather than trying to bodge it another way.

Once you have done your composer process on the server, you must remove the PHPShell or composer wrapper you created so that you don't leave any security holes.

Comment: Some production servers are not allowing access to the internet. So it is impossible to run composer update.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell the composer where your Class 'AAA\Core\Tools' is?

> You can even add your own code to the autoloader by adding an autoload field > to composer.json.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Acme\\": "src/"}
    }
}
```

Comment: I am used the same thing, as I described before in my question. All works on the localhost (on windows), but when I upload scripts on FTP without changes (Linux server) it doesn't find classes.

Answer (score 0):

Composer is not meant to be used that way (i.e. you shouldn't be manually transferring vendor directories from one environment to another).

As you add dependencies to your project, the composer.json file will contain those dependencies.  When you run composer install or update on your localhost, it "locks" the current version of those dependencies for your project and stores them in the composer.lock file.  You should be transferring the composer.json and composer.lock files from your development environment to your production environment and then running composer install on your production environment as part of your deployment process.  When you run composer install on your production environment, Composer will look at your composer.lock file and install the specified versions of the dependencies in the vendor directory of the production environment.

You may want to review the composer documentation regarding basic usage (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) and command line options (https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md) for more details.

Comment: Actually Composer is just a dependency manager and its purpose ends there. Whatever you do after you have your dependencies installed, is not Composer's concern. Some people prefer to get their dependencies during deployment using `composer install`and others prefer or are forced to package everything (_no ssh access, shareware project, deliver to the client, etc_) before _pushing to production_. The real problem is when Composer is used for something that was not designed for, like installing NPM and Bower dependencies.

Comment: Actually Composer does more than just dependency management.  `composer install` will generate the autoloader (which is something you seem to be having issues with) and run other scripts defined in the composer.json file.  See 'options' under the [install][1] command. Have you tried running `composer install` on the production environment to see if it fixes your issue?

[1]: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

Comment: (_I didn't asked the question. Please pay more attention._) The scripts feature allows you to hook and change some behavior of Composer at given points in the execution lifetime, so it is an extension to the dependency management, which many dependency and package managers have it. As for the autoloader, it offers a mapping between what _crazy stuff_ any author does at the file system level and something that can be used inside the language. You can use it or you can replace it with your own at any time.

Comment: Yes, it's true, I can't run composer on production server because I have no access to do that. That's why I want to upload locally generated `vendor/` folder.