# Why can't I run the composer script from PHP using exec, shell_exec, system?

Tags: php, composer-php, exec

I can run about any binary but not that composer.phar using PHP's `exec` or `shell_exec`.

In the same folder I have composer and another php executable with same permissions:

```
ls -lh
total 1,8M
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me me 1,8M août  22 20:48 composer.phar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 me me   39 août  22 21:05 test.php
```

Test.php contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
print 'hello';
```

I then have this script:

```
<?php
print $cmd  = "composer.phar --version 2>&1" ;
print "<br>";

$return  = exec( $cmd );
var_dump($return);

print "<br><br>";

print $cmd  = "test.php 2>&1";
print "<br>";

$return  = shell_exec( $cmd );
var_dump($return);
```

Here is what I get:

```
composer.phar --version 2>&1
[...]Process.php:81:string 'sh: 1: : Permission denied' (length=26)

test.php 2>&1
[...]Process.php:88:string 'hello' (length=5)
```

Why do I get that `string 'sh: 1: : Permission denied'` error? I tried executing in PHP with `/usr/bin/env php composer.php` `/usr/bin/php composer.php`, I get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run composer with a PHP script in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219436/run-composer-with-a-php-script-in-browser)

Comment: I just saw your note about the permissions, so it's not that. I think you have to unpack the phar. See above link.

Comment: It isn't a duplicate. Running composer programmatically from a PHP script could be a workaround but not a solution to that weird issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by disabling the xdebug extension.

From the doc:

> To improve performance when the xdebug extension is enabled, Composer
>   automatically restarts PHP without it.

So I guess that this "PHP restart" is an issue when calling the binary/phar from PHP.

It is be possible to use the environment variable `COMPOSER_ALLOW_XDEBUG` to get it working with xdebug, also disbaling a few xdebug options that could alter performances:

```
<?php
$result = shell_exec('COMPOSER_ALLOW_XDEBUG=1 /usr/bin/env php -d xdebug.remote_enable=0 -d xdebug.profiler_enable=0 -d xdebug.default_enable=0 composer.phar --version 2>&1');
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: At my side xdebug already disabled. But still not working and getting Permission issue.

Comment: So, it really should be a permission issue. My exact issue definitely was related to Xdebug being enabled. I can reproduce the issue easily by re-enabling it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work with `system('php /usr/local/bin/composer install -d /...')`, because if you just run composer directly in a shell it will work by reading the shebang at the beginning of the file that says it should be executed by php, but using `system()` you don't have a shell so you need to specify this yourself.

Comment: I get the same `sh: 1: : Permission denied error` using system. The composer you have in /usr/local/bin/composer is the same composer.phar, but without the extension.