# Run composer accross a broswser with a PHP

Tags: php, composer-php

This post is in relation with this : 
[Run composer with a PHP script in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219436/run-composer-with-a-php-script-in-browser)

My problem is to solve how to install a library without terminal and take in consideration some hosting do not accept the `exec` command.

In summary the user can just click on the button to install apps with the library

Thank you.

I tried 2 solutions :

```
  use Composer\Console\Application;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;



  putenv('COMPOSER_HOME=' . self::$root); // /www/mywebsite/shop/
  putenv('COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=' . CORE::BASE_DIRECTORY . '/Work/Cache/Composer/');
  putenv('COMPOSER_HTACCESS_PROTECT=0');
```

first with this code

```
 $stream = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
      $output = new StreamOutput($stream);
      $application = new Application();
      $application->setAutoExit(false);
      $code = $application->run(new ArrayInput(array('command' => 'install tinify/tinify')), $output);
      $result = stream_get_contents($stream);

      var_dump($code);
      var_dump($result);
```

The result is : (not work and nothing is installed)

```
int(1) string(0) ""
```

The second approach :

```
  $input = new ArrayInput(array('command' => 'install tinify/tinify'));
  $application = new Application();
  $application->setAutoExit(false); // prevent `$application->run` method from exitting the script
  $result = $application->run($input);

  var_dump($result);
```

The result is : (not work and nothing is installed)

```
 int(1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run composer with a PHP script in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219436/run-composer-with-a-php-script-in-browser)

Comment: @fonini Do you look my first sentence, it's not a duplicate. run composer in browser is the link with  Run composer with a PHP script in browser

Comment: I belive you won't be able to run any command without exec.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to run composer on the production server.

You can run composer in a project on a computer with similar software (OS, php version). Then you can copy already built project directory with vendor folder in it to the production server.

Usually you can zip/gzip it first then transfer then unzip/ungzip. For the follow up updates something like rsync may be a fast solution for updating only those parts of project folder that changed.

You may want to have a script that copies your development directory first then cleans up any personal credentials (e.g. passwords to any SaaS solutions you use for development), and then does the composer & transfer automatically.